# CI Instance in Custom Library for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a custom User library in CodeIgniter. Inside this library I would like to use other CodeIgniter libraries and helpers but I am running into erros.  Here are the steps I have taken:

1. I created the User class in a User.php file and uploaded it to applications/libraries/.
2. Inside application/config/autoload.php I am autoloading the User library.

Here is the code in my User library:

```
<?php 

    class User {

    private $CI;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->CI->load->helper('form');
        }

        public function create_login_form()
        {
            echo 'hello';
            echo $this->CI->form->form_open();
        }

    }

/* End of file User.php */
```

Then in one of my views I am using to call the create_login_form method:

```
$this->user->create_login_form()
```

It seems like the method is being called because the hello is being echoed but when it gets to using the form helper `form_open` method I am getting the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: Home::$form Filename: libraries/User.php Line Number: 46
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function form_open() on a non-object in
>   .../application/libraries/User.php on line 46

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers provide functions and not methods of some object. You can directly use `form_open()` after the Form helper is loaded.

Comment: duh thanks Narf! Just starting out using CodeIgniter, guess I still need to wrap my head around everything. A follow up question:  If I wanted to use a library method then I would have to use $this->CI->library->method() correct?

Comment: Yep. On another note - if you only need the form helper and your *User* library is set to be autoloaded, then you should just autoload the Form helper as well, so you won't need to use `get_instance()`.

Comment: Awesome and thanks for the advice! One last thing: I get how autoloading a helper would let me forgo things like get_instance() and passing a reference to the CI Object, seeing as the helper is made up of _functions_ now available to all code.  But say I know that I am going to use the Session library as well.  Even if I autoload the Session library, within my custom library I am still going to have to get a reference to the CI Object to get to Session's _methods_, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the only way that you can access other libraries from within a library.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
class User {

    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function create_login_form()
    {
        echo 'Title';
        echo form_open(); // Form open is helper. Not library
        echo 'Write something';
        echo form_close(); // Produces a closing </form> tag.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class User {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function create_login_form()
    {
        echo 'Title';
        echo form_open(); // Form open is helper. Not library
        echo 'Write something';
        echo form_close(); // Produces a closing </form> tag.
    }

}
```